# Logstash service not reading config at custom directory

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, logstash, logstash-configuration

I'm trying to set up Logstash as a service on an Ubuntu 14.04 server and want it to read my configuration from a series of files that are in a directory that isn't the default /etc/logstash/conf.d I've edited /etc/init.d/logstash so that LS_CONF_DIR is the directory I want instead of the default. When I run "service logstash configtest" I get a reply saying the configuration is OK, but when I try to start the service it doesn't work and I get the following errors in debug mode:

```
{:timestamp=>"2016-06-08T16:35:05.729000-0400", :message=>"translation missing: en.logstash.runner.configuration.file-not-found", :level=>:error, :file=>"logstash/agent.rb", :line=>"383", :method=>"create_pipeline"}
{:timestamp=>"2016-06-08T16:35:05.738000-0400", :message=>"starting agent", :level=>:info, :file=>"logstash/agent.rb", :line=>"207", :method=>"execute"}
```

I've checked permissions on the files and all user have read permission. When I run logstash from the command line with -f pointing to the directory, it runs fine.

Comment: what version of Logstash, I know configtest was bugged between 2.0 and 2.31

Comment: I'm using version 2.3.2. I actually ended up just copying the configuration files to the default directory and changing LS_CONF_DIR back to its default value and it is running fine now, though I would prefer to have LS_CONF_DIR be the other directory.